# Why is the following code not producing a link?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#content").html("<h1>Valid Types</h1><ul><li><a href='" + SITE_URL + "/Custom_App/?app_type=frame&amp;session_id=" + session_id + "&amp;cart_id= " + cart_id + ">Custom Frame</a></li></ul>");
```

It is only showing:

```
<h1>Valid Types</h1>
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

Comment: concatenate properly...

Comment: The quote at the end of the href is missing

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#content").html("<h1>Valid Types</h1><ul><li><a href=\"" + SITE_URL + "/Custom_App/?app_type=frame&amp;session_id=" + session_id + "&amp;cart_id= " + cart_id + "\">Custom Frame</a></li></ul>");
```

It should work.